# Moving common components to separate repo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, es6-modules

How do i move my react components to separate repo. I tried moving the files to separate repo and doing a npm install with the git url and tried importing them but they dont work.

Answer (score 0):

If your component have a github repo it's doesnt mean that you can use it as npm package.

NPM is a module package ecosystem for javascript and it has nothing in common with github.

It 's true that most npm package has a github repo but it's two differents things.

To achieve what you want you have to first publish your componenent in npm.
Enter this command in the root directories of your component.

```
npm init
```

this will create a package.json with informations provided by you. 
Then you give your credentials (you must create an account in npm)

```
npm login
```

And you can publish

```
npm publish
```

Only after these few steps you can start use npm install name-of-your-package

Comment: i want to directly use from git and npm supports it. Issue is i guess with what's exported